# Position dynamically textarea on image with slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to think a way to position textarea on image. For example you can see text on image inside textarea and I want to be able with slider to slide this text position up and down the image in percentages scale let's say if I select 100% text position  should be at the bottom of image, but text shouldn't go out of image bounds.

```css
img {
width: 510px;
height: 720px;
}

.wrapper {
position: relative
}

label {
position: absolute;
left: 48px;
top: 12px;
}

textarea {
background: transparent;
outline: none;
border: none;
resize: none;
line-height: 122%;
letter-spacing: -0.01em;
min-height: 100px;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" id="range">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/still-life-glass-objects-on-600w-1731010606.jpg"/>
  <label>
    <textarea>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</textarea>
  </label>
</div>
```

Been thinking of ways to make this but cant think of any good way. Maybe possible suggestions or examples with vanilla js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text not to go outside the image, then you just need to set the range of the slider as the difference between the heights of the image and the textarea:

```js
(() => {
  const img = document.querySelector(".wrapper>img")
  const slider = document.querySelector("#range")
  const imgText = document.querySelector("#img-text")
  document.addEventListener("input", function() {
    slider.max = img.clientHeight - imgText.clientHeight
    imgText.style.top = `${slider.value}px`
  })
})()
```

```css
img {
  width: 510px;
  height: 720px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48px;
  top: 12px;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  line-height: 122%;
  letter-spacing: -0.01em;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" id="range">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/still-life-glass-objects-on-600w-1731010606.jpg" />
  <label id="img-text">
        <textarea>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</textarea>
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thought of same solution, but at 100% text goes out of image bounds

Comment: in you HTML, set the max on input range on 80. Done :)

Comment: @HamiD tryed, but it doesnt work exactly the same when image sizes are different. So when image size will be in different size that 80% will be slightly at different position

Comment: Then you need to get clientHeight of your images and change it to percent. I'm not good at math ;)